# Building 64-bit (arm64) iOS app with deployment target 4.3 on Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5.1

I am able to build an iOS fat binary with 32-bit (arm7, arm7s) and 64-bit (arm64) architectures with a iOS deployment target of 4.3.  I know from Apple's 64-bit conversion guide that the minimum deployment target is supposed to be 5.1.1.

Even if Apple says the minimum iOS is supposed to be 5.1.1 for apps with an arm64 slice, will iOS 4.3 users still be able to download and use my app?  Any experiences with iOS 4.3 and 32/64-bit fat binaries out there?

Comment: Xcode 5.0 outright refuses to have a 4.3 deployment target with arm64 listed as a valid architecture. And not that I would know much more, but Apple is not known for maintaining compatibility outside their public promises.